# Binding mower motor

Tags: small-engine, lawnmower, tractor, briggs-stratton

I have a mower (or mini tractor) with a Briggs & Stratton 12 HP motor which binds quite a bit, causing it to be difficult to start. I assume that it is either due to rust / missing lubrication / a bent axle.

Once it is started it runs fine.

Is this easily corrected by taking it appart, cleaning, greasing/oiling and reassembling, or should I replace it with a newer motor?

[image: Motor birds eye view]

[image: tractors]

Answer (score 3):

More than likely the compression release mechanism isn't working correctly (stuck in the running position). When the engine is moving slow, there's a little mechanism which allows opens a valve and allows compression buildup to be released. This allows you to spin the engine fast enough to get it started. As the engine gets up to speed, the mechanism, due to inertial forces, is moved out of the way and the compression is allowed to build as it is supposed to so the engine can run correctly.

[Here is a short video on the B&S engine's compression release.](https://youtu.be/tceKAAViC1c)

It is one of two things happening. Either there is buildup around the mechanism which isn't allowing it to return to it's starting position, or the return spring has become weak/broken and isn't doing its job. You could try an engine flush to see if it'd help (as per the first scenario), but more then likely you'll need to take the engine apart to fix it. If you are mechanically inclined, you should be able to fix this at home. And knowing the price of replacement engines, it would make economical sense to fix it rather then replace it.

Comment: I was told by a local supplier that the engines I have (from the 70s) may become very hard to source spares for, but I really hope I can fix it.

Comment: @JoSSte - That cover doesn't look like an engine from the 70's.

Comment: I have three identical tractors - this one has a newer motor - the other two are definitely from the 1970s

Comment: They would have been incapable of manufacturing that label in the 1970s.  Same problem NASA had with the moon "landing"... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYFMU7XfyzE

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - According to that video, NASA was incapable of faking it ... not sure I was implying the above engine cover was faked :P

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I'm sure you weren't. I was addressing JoSSte just forgot to put the @.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - It's all good! I actually thought the post was comical (in context) and hope that's how you meant it.

Comment: Oh, of course!!!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I added more pictures - is the other motor also newer?